# Child XIB open over Main XIB

Tags: iphone

i want to open new xib(view) over the Main xib(view).

i.e Main (Parent) xib when i click on button inside parent XIB. child xib open over parent xiB, and it should see parent xib.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easiest to solve using viewControllers rather than just xib's (if that is posisble in your scenario). If each XIB is a view with a view controller then the button inside the parent XIB can alloc/init then displayModalViewController which will display the child XIB. As for allowing the child to "see" the parent: in the Model View Controller paradigm, views should not "see" each other - the controllers should update the model from their own views, and visa versa.